# Is there a theorem to observe how many root will $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ contains?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $F$ be a field and $p(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$. I know that $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ will contains a root for $p(x)$, e.g. $\Bbb Q[x]/\langle x^3-2\rangle$. But it may or may not contains all roots of $p(x)$. What I only know is  that it just contains *at least one*. Is there a theorem that can check how many roots will $F[x]/\langle p(x)\rangle$ contain under some further assumption of $p(x)$ or $F[x]$?

Comment: There was an interesting comment on my question here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2226043/how-many-roots-does-one-add-when-considering-the-quotient-of-a-polynomial-ring  (but no answer)